# What are alternatives for these controls in iPhone

Tags: iphone

**What are alternatives for these controls in iPhone**

- Radio Button
- Check Box
- Drop Down
- x raise to Power y in UILabel
- Hyperlink

Suggestion and answers will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all of these controls can be displayed using a UIWebView - if that's not an option, have a look at the UIWebView implementations and it should give you some kind of idea.

However, if you want native controls, these are probably the best options:

- Radio Button: [UISegmnetedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)
- Check Box: [UISwitch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- Drop Down: [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) (used in UIWebView).

x to the power of y in a UILabel is easy. Just replace your indices with unicode superscript characters... I use the following method to turn an integer into a string with superscript characters.

```
+(NSString *)convertIntToSuperscript:(int)i {
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"⁰", @"¹", @"²", @"³", @"⁴", @"⁵", @"⁶", @"⁷", @"⁸", @"⁹", nil];
    if (i >= 0 && i <= 9) {
        NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:i]];
        [array release];
        return myString;
    }
    else {
        NSString *base = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
        NSMutableString *newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (int b = 0; b<[base length]; b++) {
            int temp = [[base substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(b, 1)] intValue];
            [newString appendString:[array objectAtIndex:temp]];
        }
        [array release];
        NSString *returnString = [NSString stringWithString:newString];
        [newString release];
        return returnString;
    }    
}
```

For a hyperlink, use a `UITextView` with `Property Inspector -> Detection -> Links` enabled and `Editable` behavior disabled. Of course this is also available in a UIWebView.

Comment: how you wrote this in superscript, i mean combination of keys etc. ?

Comment: you need to enable the character viewer... go to System Preferences > Language & Text > Input Sources, and tick the Keyboard & Character Viewer

Comment: it should appear in the menu bar, a little icon which looks like a window with an asterix in it - click it, then click show character viewer, then click digits, and you will see the superscript chars

Comment: UISegmentedControl is nothing like a radio button.  It's the equivalent to an NSSegmentedControl.

Answer (score 7):

- Radio Button: `UISegmentedControl`
- Check Box: `UISwitch`
- Drop Down: `UIPickerView`
- x raise to Power y in UILabel: no such thing, you need to draw it
  yourself.
- Hyperlink: Use a `UILabel` and attach a gesture recognizer for taps to
  it (or a custom type button)

Comment: UISegmentedControl is not an alternative of Radio Button..thanks for quick reply, i do know these alternatives, but hidden question in this question was..why we are not provided with exact thing ?? when this is expected ??

Comment: same is case with UISwitch..lets suppose there are 3-4 options, then with Check Box we can select two, three or all. But with Radio Button we can select only one. so how can UISegmentedControl and UISwitch could be exact alternative of Radio Button and Check Box repectivly ?

Comment: @Shahab: You need to add several UISwitches for each Check Box.

Comment: and UISegmentedControl is a complete analog of Radio Button, you can select only one button at once.

Comment: @Shahab: Answering to question in your comment, there are no exact controls in iOS because they are not suitable for finger taps.

Comment: @Shabab UISegmentedControl allows a mutually exclusive selection, a switch changes state for a single item. The UIPickerView could be a replacement for the radio buttons as well. There is no reason to ask for "exact replacements" here - those that are provided work very well and are well known. Why do you think you need others?

Comment: @Shahab - In addition to what Andrey and Eiko have said, I highly recommend reading Apple's iOS Human Interface Guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html, which provides good explanations for why Apple designed these controls this way in their touch-based UI.